# Pass value in URL to wrapped URL in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am trying to send a value in a URL to Joomla (2.5)

LINK: http://www.mysite.com/index.php/our-listings/index.php?address=1234

The link is to a php script in an Iframe Wrapper.

I wish to pass the `$address` value to the script. I tried using POST and GET with not data passed.

In research online I saw this: `$address = JRequest::getVar('address');`

But where does this code go?

I tried it in the iframed script but I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'JRequest' not found  - because the script is not aware it is in Joomla i guess.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Joomla 2.5 edit components/com_wrapper/views/wrapper/view.html.php not wrapper.php

Find `$url = $params->def('url', '');`

Then add the following after it (as outlined in Abid's link)

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
  if ($key<>"option" && $key<>"Itemid") {
    $url.=(strpos($url,"?")) ? "&" : "?";
    $url.="$key=$value";
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean $key!= "option"?

Comment: It's legit: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php (even tho I prefer !=, **Edward Borland** probably used other languages where <> were used. You can use both in PHP.